# Add .well-known to asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lets-encrypt

I want to have a `.well-known` directory in my root for letsencrypt renewals.

I have added a route to `.well-known` like so:

```
 app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @".well-known")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/.well-known"),
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true // serve extensionless file
        });
```

I added a direcotry inside my wwwroot called `.well-known` but it never gets copied to the output when I publish.

I tried adding a file to it and also edit csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="wwwroot\.well-known\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Every time I publish I have to manually create the directory.  How do I get it automatically added to the wwwroot?

Comment: Publish does not include empty folders, can you maybe put a dummy.txt file and include it in the project?

Comment: yeah, I tried that `I tried adding a file to it ` sorry, should have been clearer

Comment: Did you also include it in the Visual Studio Project and set it's Build Action to `Content`?

Comment: I just tried this now.  When I select "copy always" a warning symbol appears next to it and the project will not build.  I think it is because windows won't let you create a folder with a `.` as the first character

Comment: Where you call app.UseStaticFiles in your question, can anybody confirm that this definitely does NOT interfere with the default behaviour of serving static files from within wwwroot?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I tried adding a file to it and also edit csproj:
>
> ```
> <ItemGroup>
>   <Content Include="wwwroot\.well-known\" />
> </ItemGroup>
> ```

You can't copy over folders via Content, only files. You have to change it to

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="wwwroot\**">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
<ItemGroup>
```

and like mentioned in the comments, you need to put an empty dummy file inside.

Comment: It works, I had to setup a dummy file and set the content to "Copy if newer"

Comment: @Raffaeu: That's exactly the same as above. When you set the properties in the VS IDE to "Copy if newer" it will create an `<Content Include="<filename or folder>"><CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest></CopyToOutputDirectory>` entry in your csproj

Comment: I've also ran into this issue. Although, the additional configuration in the project file works, I'd argue that this `.well-known` folder shouldn't be excluded, and treated differently. Raised [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42071) on the aspnetcore repo

Comment: The before mentioned issue is considered for .NET 7, and there is an [outstanding PR](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/26366) to fix this. For .NET 7, this exclusion is not needed anymore :)

Answer (score 11):

Another approach is to make a controller - if you have complex rules - or the file varies by domain (as it does for certain types of verification tokens).

```
public class WellKnownFileController : Controller
{
    public WellKnownFileController()
    {

    }

    [Route(".well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association")]
    public ContentResult AppleMerchantIDDomainAssociation()
    {
        switch (Request.Host.Host)
        {
            case "www2.example.com":
                return new ContentResult
                {
                    Content = @"7B227073323935343637",
                    ContentType = "text/text"
                };

            default:
                throw new Exception("Unregistered domain!");
        }
    }
}
```

You can then just hit `.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association` and get this controller.

Of course you can load the file from disk or whatever you need to do - or have a passthrough.

Comment: After many days dealing with this issue I finally adopted your approach. I was unable to serv the android `assetlinks`, I included it as `embedded resource` and got it via assembly.`GetManifestResourceNames`

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me...

In csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="wwwroot\.well-known\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

In Startup.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles(); // <-- don't forget this
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
     FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot/.well-known")),
     RequestPath = new PathString("/.well-known"),
     ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add the below code to the `MyProject.csproj` file

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include=".well-known\acme-challenge\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```